# Force ampscript to display result in editor instead of switching to preview

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have created a piece of ampscript that retrieves the images url from a data extension based on the SKU of a product.
The SKU is injected in the code. 
Everything works but the ampscript loads once we move into preview.

Is there a way to force the ampscript to load the content in the editor?
I thought potentially with treatascontent function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ampscript is only rendered during sendtime, and 'Send preview' is mimicking the sendtime behavior without sending. `Treatascontent()` tells the system to render ampscript nested within, as opposed to treating it as a string. This is useful if you are pulling ampscript dynamically from a DE field.